# Почему вызывается метод Destroy в фрагментах в ViewPager при листании?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

У меня есть фрагмент и внутри его я вызываю 3 фрагмента с помощю табы,
когда я переключаю между первым и вторым,то все нормально и фрагменты не уничтожаются, но когда я переключаю с вторым к третьем то , тогда умирает первый фрагмент и вызвается метод Destroy.

может кто нибудь объяснить в чем проблема , или так дольжно быт ???

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private static final int NUM_PAGES=3;
        private Context mContext;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,Context mContext) {
        super(fm);
        this.mContext=mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch(position){
            case 0 :
                AnimalsFragment animalsFragment = new AnimalsFragment();
                return animalsFragment;
            case 1:
                BirdsFragment birdsFragment = new BirdsFragment();
                return birdsFragment;
            case 2:
                InsectsFragment insectsFragment = new InsectsFragment();
                return insectsFragment;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    //Total num of fragments
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

    //Return page title depending on position
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.animals) ;
            case 1:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.birds) ;
            case 2:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.insects) ;

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё происходит так, как и должно быть. `ViewPager` сохраняет по умолчанию в памяти только текущий, отображаемый фрагмент + фрагменты слева и справа от текущего. Т.е. всего три. В случае отображения первого и последнего фрагментов в памяти хранятся только 2 фрагмента.

Изменить это поведение по умолчанию можно методом `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int pageLimit)`. В случае с тремя фрагментами надо передать число `2` в метод сей:

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
//теперь при переключении меж фрагментами будут сохраняться помимо отображаемого по два фрагмента слева и стправа от текущего, т.е. все 3 в любом случае.
```

Comment: а где надо вызвать его , я его вызвал в нутри главного фрагмента в методе onCreateView и получил NullPointerException

Comment: Спасибо большое , получилось .

Comment: @o.m.k, пожалуйста) Кстати, вы помимо принятия ответа (галочка) можете, также, проголосовать за него (стрелочка вверх сверху от галочки) =)